# Animation as shown in the link

Tags: page-template

I wish to have an animation shown in this link http://krixisolutions.com/
How do i get this? Add CSS animation as Preloader to WordPress 1

Answer (score 0):

Checking out the source code on the page I see the cards are svg and are run by css transitions like this:

```
    .svg-cards {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20vmin;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 100px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: -30px -30px 40px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    line-height: 0;
}
.svg-cards.rotation {
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.6s;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.01, 0.74, 0.28, 1.01);
    -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.01, 0.74, 0.28, 1.01);
    -ms-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.01, 0.74, 0.28, 1.01);
    -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.01, 0.74, 0.28, 1.01);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.01, 0.74, 0.28, 1.01);
}
```

Create your cards, then apply the appropriate transitons you want, both "rotation" and "scale" to make them zoom in.

This isn't technically a preloader but a section that is sized to fit the browser window using JavaScript on window load.